# Azeroth Core - Don't see data in table areatable_dbc

Tags: database, view, dbeaver, azerothcore

I wanted to change some stuff regarding zones in db, but see no data in tables. Is it possible that this is protected from viewing/editing? Or this data is just not used anymore by the core and I need to look somewhere else.

Table `areatable_dbc`

I'm new to this stuff so any advice will be helpful. Thank you

[image: areatable_dbc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That table can be used to override data from the [area.dbc](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/AreaTable) file

From this [topic](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/584):

> Those tables must be there allowing people to create their set of data
> or just customize the dbc. The cases are essentially the following:
>
> - tables empty, DBC files installed (classic way)
> - tables with some custom data + DBC files installed (to easily customize DBC that are not needed to be installed in the client too)
> - no DBC files installed and personal data inside those tables (you're using azerothcore for your MMO project)

There is a file attached to the release [3.0.0-dev](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/releases/tag/v3.0.0-dev) containing the default data for the dbc tables if you need to customize them.

**Note**: keep in mind that certain dbc changes require also client modification, there are very few dbc that are exempt by the client mod.

Comment: Throws at me this error message when I try to extract Archive: AzerothcoreDBCToSQL.zip

Error: Missing Volume: AzerothcoreDBCToSQL.z01
Any idea where can I get that too ? Thanks

Comment: just updated it. download it again please